# Why do some LibreOffice templates fail to run in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, libreoffice

I'm running Xubuntu 17.04, and I'm using LibreOffice Calc for my data.

LibreOffice Calc technically runs fine, but I thought:

> *Hey, why not try the other LibreOffice template?*

So I tried to run LibreOffice Web, but then a problem occurred... LibreOffice closed when I tried to run it, and the other LibreOffice's I had open froze until it showed the "Internal Error" window, then the rest of the LibreOffice's open closed as well.

#### Question:

How can I have all of the LibreOffice templates run?

P.S.
My LibreOffice version is
`LibreOffice 5.3.1.2 30m0(Build:2)`